# How to test for differences from baseline where dependent variable is non-normally distributed using SPSS?

Tags: spss, nonparametric

I have some physiological measurements which consist of 4 events measured in a "during task" condition and preceded and followed by a rest period.

I want to test that the data points immediately preceding the 4 events do not differ from the rest baseline, calculated as the average of the values in the start and end rest periods.

My problem is that I have measurements from 13 subjects, 3 session each, each session consisting of 9 of these measurement blocks.

To make all the data comparable, I subtracted the baseline from the values preceding each event, so that the test would now be against zero for all of them.

Given that the distribution of the values is not normal, how should I conduct a test in SPSS (PASW v. 18) to prove that overall these data points are not significantly different from zero, resulting in one statistic to report?

Comment: Picture Is Worth 1,000 Words Dept.:  could you post a table showing how your data are structured?

Comment: What is the distribution of the dependent variable? What exact physiological measure are you actually taking (this might suggest particular distributional issues)? Are you also asking about strategies for aggregating and calculating an overall difference from rest period for each participant? Or are we to assume that this is fixed, and that your dataset consists of one score for each participant? Are you interested in the effect of session?